# Idiom for "distort": starts with "play"

Tags: idiom-requests

I can't remember how the idiom goes, I believe the pattern is

> verb adverb and adverb *with* [the truth]

I think *verb* is "play."  I think the adverbs don't end in *ly*.  Maybe the second adverb is "free."

The idiom means **to distort**.

I tried a dictionary of idioms but didn't find it.

Comment: Probably *play fast and loose*.

Comment: @StoneyB you should make that an answer.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you very much for your quick reply.  That was it exactly.  Please make an answer so I can hit "accept."  I personally will not mind if you don't do a good job with documentation.

Comment: But documentation is the *fun* part of answering!

Comment: @StoneyB - some people hesitate to turn comments into answers because they're lazy, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Play fast and loose with X* has been around a long time; it goes back to at least the 16th century. Robert Nares' magnificently titled *A Glossary; or, Collection of Words, Phrases, Names, and Allusions to Customs, Proverbs, Etc., Which Have Been Thought to Require Illustration in the Works of English Authors, Particularly Shakespeare and His Contemporaries*, 1822<sup>†</sup>, derives it from

> A cheating game, whereby gipsies and other vagrants beguiled the common people of their money. It is said to be still used by low sharpers and is called *pricking at the belt*, or *girdle*. It is thus described: ‘A leathern belt is made up into a number of intricate folds and placed edgewise upon a table. One of the folds is made to resemble the middle of the girdle, so that whosoever should thrust a skewer into it would think he held it fast to the table; whereas, when he has so done, the person with whom he plays may take hold of both ends and draw it away.’ —Sir J. Hawkins, [note on ‘Like a right gipsey, hath, at fast and loose, Beguil’d me to the very heart of loss.’ - *Ant. & Cleo.*, IV, xii, 28.

In other words, you *think* you've got it pinned down, but you're wrong.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>But I don't actually know that what follows is from that edition; this is quoted from Furness' *New Variorum* edition of *KJ*. I consulted *A New Edition, with Considerable Additions Both of Words and Examples, by James O. Halliwell, Esq., F.R.S., &c., and Thomas Wright, Esq., M.A., F.S.A.* 1858, and found a somewhat longer version there.</sub>